# Laravel upgrade 5.0 to 5.1 login issue

Tags: laravel, authentication, upgrade

After upgrading Laravel from 5.0 to 5.1 I have issue with login users in my AuthController.

Old constructor:

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->registrar = $registrar;

    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

New constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

And here don't work `$this->auth->login($user);`

```
public function getConfirmation($confirmationCode = null)
{
    if ($confirmationCode) {
        $user = User::where('confirmation_code', '=', $confirmationCode)->first();

        if ($user) {
            $user->update([
                'confirmed'         => 1,
                'confirmation_code' => null
            ]);

            $this->auth->login($user);
            return redirect()->action('UserUserController@info_page', $user->name);
        }
    }

    return view('auth.confirm');
}
```

How I must change `$this->auth->login($user)`?

Comment: have you tried clearing cache & `composer dump autoload`?

Comment: Try Auth::login($user)

Comment: What doesn't work?? Please give the exception it throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Facade:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods

So:

```
use Auth; // Of course use the Facade.

...

Auth::login($user);
```

I started with laravel 5.2 so I don't know if the facade is in the `config/app.php` by default. If not you should add the `Auth` facade to the `config/app.php`